# Display the Content of a Post with qTip2

Tags: posts, the-content

How would/should I use [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) to display the `the_content();` of a WordPress post?

I've been trying to accomplish this for a month now. I got it working once, but it wouldn't display the content that was placed after a `<br>`. I no longer have the code, unfortunately.

I found the code, which worked before, but sadly, couldn't handle line breaks, `<br>`:
http://jsfiddle.net/jv8WN/7/

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have so far? Or did you mean you have **no code at all**? I understood that you don't have any **working code**.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I used once.

Comment: You have any idea, @tf?

Comment: Well, I looked into the fiddle, but what I (or other people here) need, is some actual example bringing this into WordPress context. How/Where did you include qTip to display the content? What is not working?

Comment: Well, in the Fiddle, when you hover over the BMW-logo, the text `Hello, I'm text!` will appear. That text is taken from a WordPress post I made called `BMW Sponsor` with the content, `Hello, I'm text!`. The logos are all posts displayed in a top-bar with a featured image. The problem I have, is when I display text in WordPress' text-editor and I hit Enter to skip down a line or two, the text after the line break won't display in the tooltip. Why is that?

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing here, but the script depends on paragraph tags. WordPress, however, is using `autop`, so a new line will end the current paragraph, and optional following text is placed inside a new paragraph. Maybe try using `<br />`...?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
<div id="sponsors">
<div class="wrap">
        <h1><span>Our Corporate Sponsors</span></h1>

    <ul class="lcp_catlist">
        <li>
             <h5 class="header-sponsor-title"><a href="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/global-imports-bmw-2/" title="Global Imports BMW">Global Imports BMW</a></h5><a href="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/global-imports-bmw-2/"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/bmw-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-50x50 wp-post-image" alt="DACC Sponsor" /></a>

            <span>Hello, I'm text!</span>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h5 class="header-sponsor-title"><a href="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/caroline-e-taylor-llc-2/" title="Caroline E. Taylor, LLC">Caroline E. Taylor, LLC</a></h5><a href="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/caroline-e-taylor-llc-2/"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://dacc.fredrixdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/caroline-e-taylor-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-50x50 wp-post-image" alt="DACC Sponsor" /></a>

            <span>
                <p>Me too!<br />New line.</p>
                <p>But I have several lines, yay!</p>
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

As I'm using `span` instead of `p`, I had to adapt the CSS:

```
#sponsors .wrap .lcp_catlist li span {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.lcp_catlist a img').each(function () {
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: $(this).parent().next('span')[0].innerHTML
                });
            });
        });
```

Basically, you just have to wrap the post content into `span` tags, that's it.

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jv8WN/33/

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet. Will this work with `the_content();`? The idea with this is it has to work through the WordPress Text Editor.